# How do I use SHIFT() method in js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I try to delete the first element by using the shift() method. But it did not work. How do I use to correct this function?

```
     `// id="delete-first" in HTML
     // the element into the array displayed in HTML 
     // I want to delete the first element
    $("#delete-first").click(function(){ 
        $("#list-student").shift(); // I have issue this line
        // $("list-student").first().remove(); // this code is not working too.
    });`

Please, fix it to help me. 
Sincerely.
```

Comment: Please add your HTML code.

Comment: Should be seeing an error in browser dev tools console(F12) that *"shift is not a function"*. Always check errors and include them in questions. That error would then prompt you to go to the jQeury api docs and figure out it doesn't exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you did not post your HTML snippet this is based on the assumption that the list items are actually the children in the `#list-student` element. So the only thing that you're missing is the # as mentioned in the comment, and also getting the children elements before using `.first()`

```
$("#delete-first").click(function(){
    $("#list-student").children().first().remove();
});
```

If you are actually having all the list items with the same ID of `#list-student` (which is not advisable), then you can do

```
$("#delete-first").click(function(){
    $("[id=list-student]:first").remove();
});
```

Comment: What's with `$( $(selector) )` ? Also that selector is looking for `<list-student></list-student>` element

Comment: It's wrapping the HTML element returned from the `.first()` method. Oops I didn't notice that, will update it.

Comment: That wrapper `$()` is completely redundant. Will work fine without it

Comment: Oh right, checked the jQuery documentation it is redundant. I was thinking about the `.get()` method in jQuery

Comment: Generally each method in chain receives what was returned from previous method

Comment: Not for the `.get(index)` method (https://api.jquery.com/get/#get-index). Anyway, I've updated the answer

Comment: Right ...that's why I said "generally". Methods the are used as getters don't

Comment: Yeah, I was still confused between these two methods apparently

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to remove the first occurrence of the `#list-student` item - just select it and use `remove`:

```
$("#list-student").remove();
```

You don't need to select the first element because IDs are unique.